# Time based event in jQuery to display random images

Tags: jquery, events

Instead of a user event such as an on click event, I am trying to execute an animation (3 second animation) of an image, and then in another 3 seconds I want that image to change.

So basically I need to loop through an array of images, and replace the image every 3 seconds without any events being triggered.

Any suggestions? I thought about setInterval(3000) but then how does that work..

```
    var images = [
    "assets/images/s1-person1.svg",
    "assets/images/s1-person2.svg",
    "assets/images/s1-person3.svg",
    "assets/images/s1-person4.svg",
    "assets/images/s1-person5.svg",
    "assets/images/s1-person6.svg",
    "assets/images/s1-person7.svg",
    "assets/images/s1-person8.svg"
];

function change() {
    var i;
    for (i == 0; i <= images.length; i++) {
        var random = Math.floor( Math.random() * images.length);
        $(".s1-person-1").attr('src', images[random]);
    }
}
var intervalID = window.setInterval(change, 3000);
```

Comment: Documentation and example of using setInterval https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: `for (i=0;i<images.length;i++){`, not `==` and not `<=`

Comment: @Huangism, I updated the text but it doesn't do anything yet. The console returns change() as undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The loop is useless here. You are doing the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to @huangism and @DatGeoudon for pointing me in the right direction.

```
    var images = [
    "assets/images/s1-person1.svg",
    "assets/images/s1-person2.svg",
    "assets/images/s1-person3.svg",
    "assets/images/s1-person4.svg",
    "assets/images/s1-person5.svg",
    "assets/images/s1-person6.svg",
    "assets/images/s1-person7.svg",
    "assets/images/s1-person8.svg"
];

function change() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i <= images.length; i++) {
        var random = Math.floor( Math.random() * images.length);
        $(".s1-person-1").attr('src', images[random]);
    }
}
var intervalID = window.setInterval(change, 3000);
```

Comment: Good on you figuring this out yourself, it doesn't happen that often on here